# Curl not executing even after enabling it in PHP.INI file

Tags: php, curl, php-ini

I'm using the following code to execute a curl. But after running it produces not output. I'm sure that I've enabled curl in php.ini by removing ';'. Also tried phpinfo(); That also said curl is enabled. Still, my code isn't working! Not even an error as output.

```
<?php
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  $token = ""; //token from fb
  $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token='.$token;
  $ch = curl_init($url);
  $jsonData = '{
      "recipient":{
          "id":"1250896051638221"
      },
      "message":{
          "text":"5"
      }
  }';
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonData);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  print_r($result);
?>
```

I'm using a Windows Machine (windows 10) with XAMPP (php7)

Comment: Are you running the script from cli? it could have a different configuration. or try `curl_error($ch)` when `$result` is false

Comment: No, i'm executing it in browser. Where should I put curl_error($ch)?

Comment: after the `curl_exec($ch)` curl_error returns a string containing the last error for the current session

Comment: Got it. It says "SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate"

Comment: Don’t use print_r (it won’t give you any output if the value is `false`) – use var_dump.

Comment: Looks like curl/php can't access the CA files. what does the curl section in phpinfo() shows you? The facebook cert is fine so

Comment: Don't you need `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` set to true as well?

Comment: I finally made it work, added "curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution myself. Just turn off ssl verification

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```